# How to convert errors_on to RSpec 3 syntax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I recently upgraded from RSpec 2.99 to RSpec 3. This would be one of my specs:

```
require 'spec_helper'

  describe User, :type => :model do

    it "is invalid without a password" do
      expect(FactoryGirl.build(:user, :password => nil).errors_on(:password).size).to eq(1)      
    end

  end

end
```

I already ran the Transpec gem that is supposed to convert most of my specs to RSpec 3 syntax. However, I am still getting this error (and a few others):

```
 Failure/Error: expect(FactoryGirl.build(:user, :password => nil).errors_on(:password).size).to eq(1)
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `errors_on' for #<User:0x00000108beaba0>
```

I tried to re-write the test in a number of different ways but the error won't go away.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it exists in [rspec-collection_matchers](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-collection_matchers). Also from [this issue](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/948) you can monkey patch it.

Answer (score 13):

If you don't want to bundle another gem, you can call `valid?` on the test subject and then access the `errors` array:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User, type: :model do

  it 'is invalid without a password' do
    user = FactoryGirl.build(:user, password: nil)
    user.valid?
    expect(user.errors[:password].size).to eq(1)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach is:

```
it "is not valid without a correct email format" do
  user.email = 'user-email.com'
  user.valid?

  expect(errors_from session_form, :email).to include('is invalid')
end

def errors_from(record, attr)
  record.errors[attr].to_sentence
end
```